# How to fetch text from .srt file for a given timestamp in Python

Tags: python, subtitle

I've browsed through a handful of python subtitle libraries (pysrt, pysubs2, srt) but have yet to find a straightforward way to extract an srt entry from a file at a given timestamp. Any direction is appreciated.

```
cat subtitle_file.srt
```

> ...
>
> 7
>
> 00:00:49,450 --> 00:00:51,219
>
> Exactly as they looked
>
> 8
>
> 00:00:51,252 --> 00:00:53,454
>
> Performing on the ed sullivan show.
>
> ...

-

```
>>> import SUBTITLE_LIBRARY
>>> subs = SUBTITLE_LIBRARY.load("subtitle_file.srt")
>>> subs.getSubtitleEntry(t=51.500)
Performing on the ed sullivan show.
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [pysrt](https://pypi.org/project/pysrt/), which can load and slice subtitles from an srt file.

Your code would look like this:

```
import pysrt

subs = pysrt.open('subtitle_file.srt')
parts = subs.slice(starts_before={'minutes': 0, 'seconds': 51.500}, ends_after={'minutes': 0, 'seconds': 51.500})

for part in parts:
    print(part)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.